# Angular2 for Custom HTML Webresources in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: angular, dynamics-crm, webresource

Did anyone try to use Angular2 for the custom development of webresource in Dynamics CRM 2016? I looked up some resources but all I can find is how to include AngularJS like [here](https://zsoltzombik.com/2014/10/07/how-to-use-angularjs-for-dynamics-crm-development/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I've created [a quickstart project](https://github.com/camelCaseDave/xrm-spa-ng-adal) which aims to support building single page applications for Dynamics CRM in Angular. The project uses ADAL to authenticate with Dynamics.

Comment: And you added all the .js libraries as webresources in CRM? (this is my first CRM development project)

Comment: @Bianca I would use a tool like webpack to compile all of my .js files into one .js file and my .css files into one .css file. Third party .js files like angular and bootstrap however, I'd deploy as their own minified files to CRM.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm coming from a custom development background and felt a bit lost within the constraints of CRM custom web resources development. I'm looking into webpack and also SystemJS and I saw that the alternatives are very nicely explained on the Angular site -> https://angular.io/guide/deployment#webpack.